# Databricks save Rdata file to AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: r, databricks

I have developed a model in R using databricks. I want to save the output datafile on AWS S3 bucket but when I save the file as below it does not save to the mounted drive.

```
doc <- save(data, file=paste0(getwd(), "/datafile.RData"))
```

What is the best way to mount data to S3 using R?

I have tried the below sample code and it works so I know my connection between AWS and Databricks is working.

```
%python
display(dbutils.fs.ls("/"))
```

Answer (score 1):

From Databricks File System (DBFS) [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html#local-file-apis):

> You can use local file APIs to read and write to DBFS paths.
> Databricks configures each cluster node with a FUSE mount /dbfs that
> allows processes running on cluster nodes to read and write to the
> underlying distributed storage layer with local file APIs. When using
> local file APIs, you must provide the path under /dbfs.

For example:

```
save(data, file="/dbfs/datafile.RData")
```

Comment: another possibility is to save file locally, into `/tmp`, or something like, and then use `dbutils.fs.cp` or `%fs cp` to copy it to the cloud storage

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the question about saving to s3 bucket. saving to dbfs is easy. This is not an s3.